# Entity showing tables through foreign key relationship in controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, swagger

I'm writing my first webapi2 controller application to be hosted on Azure.

I'm using swagger to test the apis out.

I'm now on writing the first method to write to the database through the webapi2 controller method.

When I go into swagger to test the method I see in the "example value" the table I'm working on writing to as well as all of the tables that have relationships to it.

This throws up a red flag to me because someone could then write values directly into those tables based on what I'm seeing without fettering out.

The example table is an account table:

```
{    
    "id": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "UserLevel": [
    {
        "pk": "string",
        "fkAccount": "string",
        "Level": 0
    }
}
```

My area of concern is the UserLevel which I only want to set on the back end.  I don't want this visible to be set through the API.

The controller code is this:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutAccount(string id, Account Account)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != Account.id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(Account).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!AccountExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

So two questions:
1) Am I correct in assuming this would give the ability to set the "Level" in the UserLevel table with what is shown above?
2) How to I prevent this from happening / only allow to write back to the one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an AccountDTO class with only the properties you want to modify and setting them to the Account object, or you could get the Account in the database, and update each field manually (more or less the same, considering you have the data access in your controller).

If you want to update just a few properties, I would receive those properties as parameteres, not the entire Account object.